# Getting CPU temp from the command line

Tags: cpu, temperature, sensors

What is the best way to get the CPU temperature on Linux from the command line?

On one small portable system, I was able to get the CPU temperature from here:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

or here:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
```

However some people say to look for the "coretemp" value, which doesn't seem to exist on my system.

Is there an official best practice for getting CPU temperature?

Comment: May be dependent on Distro, but e.g. Linux Mint has a `sensors` command. Also a whole world (well, 10KB) of `sensors.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values from `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp` and know what they correspond by reading the matching thermal_zone* `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type`

So this ([taken from here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-cpu-temp)) will list the available types and readings:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp)
```

Comment: What are the thermal zones 0 and 1 in reference to?

Comment: As far as I know, it depends on the hardware and the modules. I just checked a raspberry 2 and it only has one thermal zone, identified as cpu-thermal, while two other desktops return two and three readings each, with other names. Probably `sensors` is a safer/easier bet. Given the array of hardware Linux runs on, I don't think there is a general way to do it without some additional hardware related mapping. Loading a module like coretemp may expose more information that you *could* pick up by reading other files inside the thermal_zone folder or get directly from `sensors`.